# How to optimize an MCS calculation with rdkit?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, rdkit

I am trying to run a code in which I need to perform a pairwise similarity calculation for a set of molecules in a database and to calculate their MCS if they meet a condition. At first, I was doing this using `itertools` from python, but I have thought that maybe using the `rdkit` cartridge would make it faster.

I have succeeded in calculating the pairwise similarity with a cross join, but I would like to compute also their MCS and I cannot make the function `fmcs` work.

```
select foo.mol_inchikey, boo.mol_inchikey, foo.mol_ecfp4_sfp, boo.mol_ecfp4_sfp, dice_sml(foo.mol_ecfp4_sfp, boo.mol_ecfp4_sfp) as sml, fmcs_smiles(foo.mol_mol::text, boo.mol_mol::text) as mcs from (select distinct(m.mol_inchikey), m.mol_ecfp4_sfp, m.mol_mol from cipsi_prototype.molecule m inner join cipsi_prototype.pat2mol pm on pm.mol_inchikey = m.mol_inchikey) as foo cross join (select distinct(m.mol_inchikey), m.mol_ecfp4_sfp, m.mol_mol from cipsi_prototype.molecule m inner join cipsi_prototype.pat2mol pm on pm.mol_inchikey = m.mol_inchikey) as boo
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to improve the performance of the MCS calculation ion in Python? I am currently computing it like this:

```
rdFMCS.FindMCS([molecules[mol1]['mol'], molecules[mol2]['mol']], ringMatchesRingOnly=True, completeRingsOnly=True, timeout=1).smartsString
```

Thank you

Comment: You should format your query to be readable.

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? The [rdkit tag at MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdkit) has 95.5% of its questions answered. If you want this question migrated there, please ping me by typing @Nike in a comment and letting me know. I'll make a case to the moderators for a migration.

Comment: Hi! No, I have not. It would be nice if you could migrate the question @Nike